# Midi keyboard or digital piano for beginners?

Tags: midi, piano

I am a game developer.I want to make music for my games with fl studio.
Should I use a Midi keyboard or a digital piano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the keyboard to piano roll feature in FL Studio doesn't quite do it for you a midi keyboard will - digital pianos are made to be played standalone though some can be connected to the computer.

Automation is a big part of computer music and a midi controller that also features knobs can prove really useful along the road. [image]

Faders are nice as well for controlling mixer levels, yet this is easly done with the mouse. 
Drum pads are also cool for making beats or choping and re-sampling stuff

These are all optional features and usualy cost more to have them all in one package and as a visual representation of the usefulness of feature, my opinion is keyboard > knobs > transport buttons > drum pads > faders

Answer (score 0):

You should use the piano roll. FL Studio's is really good and a midi keyboard is not necessary.  If you have a higher budget though, and really prefer it, you can buy one, but I really don't think it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

All modern digital pianos have MIDI included.

If the goal is to have the most realistic keys I would go with [this advanced MIDI keyboard](https://www.allpianos.com/digital) using Keyscape or Ravenscroft samplings.